# pandas transpose select - do analysis along transposed Series

Tags: python, pandas

`transpose` works well if just transposing `rows` and `columns`, but how does one do a `transpose with selection`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2012,2013,2014, 2012,2013,2014], 'barber': ['Sue', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike'], 'num_haircuts': [3,3,1,0,0,6]})
```

***df:***

```
  barber  num_haircuts  year
0    Sue             3  2012
1    Sue             3  2013
2    Sue             1  2014
3   Mike             0  2012
4   Mike             0  2013
5   Mike             6  2014
```

***desired df:***

```
barber 2012 2013 2014
Sue      3    3    1
Mike     0    0    6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivot:

```
df.pivot(index='barber', columns='year', values='num_haircuts')
Out: 
year    2012  2013  2014
barber                  
Mike       0     0     6
Sue        3     3     1
```